# DSoma utilizando o formulário como fonte

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

Halp!

Eu preciso que um campo texto no meu formulário mostre a soma de um determinado campo, onde o formulário é a fonte utilizando um critério.

Eu consigo que o DSoma execute com o código abaixo. No entanto, como a fonte é a tabela, o resultado não atualiza conforme eu vou filtrando meu formulário.

```
=DSoma([valor_total];[t_registros];[t_cat_entradas_saidas_ID]=1)
```

Não consegui descobrir uma forma de referenciar o formulário no campo 2 do DSoma.
É Possível?

Existe alguma forma de contornar via VBA? De repente dentro do procedimento de filtragem do formulário?

Seção de seleção e filtro
[image: Seção de seleção e filtro]

Campo texto Receitas
[image: Campo texto Receitas]

Comment: Eu pensei em utilizar o procedimento que filtra o formulário para inserir o DSoma no campo texto com os critérios do filtro. No entanto não sei como inserir o DSoma na fonte de controle do campo texto via VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui descobrir como resolver o problema.

Alimentei meu campo texto via VBA mesmo.

```
Dim txtReceitas AS Currency
Dim txtDespesas AS Currency

txtReceitas = Nz(DSum("[valor_total]", "t_registros", strWhere & "AND [t_cat_entradas_saidas_ID] = 1"), 0)
Me.txt_Receitas = txtReceitas

txtDespesas = Nz(DSum("[valor_total]", "t_registros", strWhere & "AND [t_cat_entradas_saidas_ID] = 2"), 0)
Me.txt_Despesas = txtDespesas
```

Super simples, mas como conheço pouco de VBA me bati pra achar a resposta.